# Include Blade View base on HTML On Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a partial blade view here

```
{{-- Modal --}}
@foreach( $accounts as $account )

<?php

    $id = $account->account_id;
    $follow_me = VSE::follow_me($id)['follow_me'];
    ($follow_me == true) ? $follow_me = 1 : $follow_me = 0;

    $user = DB::table('users')->where('account_id','=',$id)->first();
    if($user!= null){
        $auto_provisioning = $user->auto_provisioning;
    }

    $old_customer_type = $account->customer_type;
    $service_plans = DB::table('service_plans')->get();

?>

<div class="modal fade account-edit-{{$id}} in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body">

        {!! Form::model($account,array('route' => array('account.update', $id ),'method' => 'PUT','data-id'=>$id )) !!}

                <h3 class="nomargin">Edit account  </h3>

                {{-- Type --}}
                <div class="row mb10">

                    <div class="col-sm-2 mb10">
                        <label class="control-label" id="account_type">Account Type</label>
                         {!! Form::select('account_type',
                            array( 'customer' => 'Customer','admin-super' => 'Admin-super','admin' => 'Admin','admin-readonly' => 'Admin-readonly'),
                            $account->account_type,
                            array('class' => 'form-control input-sm') )
                        !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2 mb10">
                        <label class="control-label" id="customer_type">Customer Type</label>
                        {!! Form::select('customer_type',
                            array( '1' => 'Business',
                            '2' => 'Residential',
                            '3' => 'Small Business'
                            ),
                            $account->customer_type,
                            array('class' => 'form-control input-sm') )
                        !!}
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-2 mb5">
                        <label class="control-label">Follow-Me</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="follow_me_switch-{{$id}}" value="{{ $follow_me }}">
                        <input type="text" name="follow_me_switch" id="follow_me_input-{{$id}}" value="{{ $follow_me }}" hidden >
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label class="control-label">Auto Provisioning</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="auto_provisioning_switch" id="auto_provisioning_switch-{{$id}}" value="{{ $auto_provisioning or '' }}">
                        <input type="text" id="auto_provisioning_input-{{$id}}" name="auto_provisioning_switch_input" hidden >
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="display: none;" id="service_plan_div-{{$id}}">
                        <label class="control-label">Service Plan</label><br>
                        <select type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="service_plan" id="service_plan-{{$id}}">
                            @foreach($service_plans as $service_plan )
                                <option value="{{ $service_plan->name or '' }}">
                               {{ ucfirst($service_plan->name) }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>

                    </div>

                </div>


                {{-- Name --}}
                <label class="control-label req">Name</label>
                <div class="row mb10">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Firstname" value="{{$account->first_name or ''}}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Lastname" value="{{$account->last_name or ''}}" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="mb10">
                    <label class="control-label">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" name="email_address" placeholder="Email" value="{{$account->email_address or ''}}">
                </div>

                <label class="control-label req">Password</label>
                <div class="row mb10">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="{{$account->password or ''}}" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <label class="control-label req">Address</label>
                <div class="row mb10">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb5">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" placeholder="address1" value="{{$account->address1 or ''}}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" placeholder="address2" value="{{$account->address2 or ''}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb10">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 mb5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="city" value="{{$account->city or ''}}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 mb5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" placeholder="state" value="{{$account->state or ''}}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 mb5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postal_code" placeholder="postal_code" value="{{$account->postal_code or ''}}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nation_code" placeholder="nation_code" value="{{$account->nation_code or ''}}" required>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <label class="control-label req">Phone</label>
                <div class="row mb10">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone1" placeholder="Phone Number" value="{{$account->phone1 or ''}}" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger ">Cancel </a>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">Done</button>

            {!! Form::hidden('old_customer_type', $old_customer_type )!!}
            {!! Form::hidden('id', $id )!!}
            {!! Form::close();!!}


        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



@endforeach
```

---

It is nothing but this : @include('account.modal.account.edit')

---

How do I include that base on jQuery On Click ?

Is this possible ? Should I start thinking for anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think different - server code is working before browser gets this html. To add html after click it must be done by ajax call where server sends this part of html and javascript attach it to DOM structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [**Handlebars**](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

You have to add this script in your code

```
<script id="account-tmpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">@include('account.modal.account.edit')</script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js') }}"></script>
```

Then, compile the handlebars on click function like

```
Handlebars.compile($("#account-tmpl").html());
```

And you have to pass the dynamic values in blade by ajax get request.

Comment: I really think this should be the accepted answer. You don't always have ajax calls and sometimes you want to trigger a DOM change on click